# How to write a function that rounds the value to nearest 16th

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make a game in which each tile has a height and width of 16. Whenever the mouse is clicked instead of getting the x and y values in steps of 1, I want them in steps of 16.

The reason I want it in steps of 16 is that I use an array of objects to store all the tiles. To get the index of the array I need accurate x and y values.

*The code for converting from steps of 1 to steps of 16:*

`x = math.floor(math.floor(math.floor(x/(8/3))/16)*16)-32`

`y = math.floor(math.floor(math.floor(y/(8/3))/16)*16)-48`

the x and y are from the function `love.mousepressed(x,y,button)`

Comment: read [Lua Reference Manual 3.4.11 Funtion Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function round16(x)
  return 16*(math.floor(x/16+0.5))
end
```

or this for Lua 5.3+ if `x` is an integer

```
function round16(x)
  return 16*((x+8)//16)
end
```